# how to format the output of a cat expression

Tags: sorting, command-line, format, cut

I have a file in this format:

```
event: event1
event: event2
event: event2
event: event3
```

With this command:

```
cat event.txt |  cut -d : -f2 |sort |uniq -c |sort -n
```

I get this result:

```
1 event1
1 event3
2 event2
```

I would like to have instead an output like that:

```
event1 1
event2 2
event3 1
```

Do you have any idea of a way to do that?

Comment: do you want the result to follow the order in input file? or want the result to be sorted by the "eventID/No"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your output to be sorted by eventID like `event[1] event[2] ...` just take fedorqui's solution.

If you want your output to keep the original order of col2 in input file:

```
awk -F': *' 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next}$2 in c{print $2,c[$2];delete c[$2]}' file file
```

an example:

```
kent$  cat f
event: event1
event: event2
event: event2
event: event4
event: event4
event: event3

kent$  awk -F': *' 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++;next}$2 in c{print $2,c[$2];delete c[$2]}' f f 
event1 1
event2 2
event4 2
event3 1
```